# htaccess/nginx create time out for direct link

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

This is my actual link :

```
http://dl.mysite.com/premium/folder/file.mkv
```

And I want users not allow access to actual link and I want change links to another link :

```
http://dl.mysite.com/{random-string}/folder/file.mkv
http://dl.mysite.com/aaabbbbnnnnn/folder/file.mkv
http://dl.mysite.com/99iiissskkka/folder/file.mkv
http://dl.mysite.com/bbnnmkkaaaww/folder/file.mkv
```

And this link expire after 3 days

Comment: So are you currently using Apache or Nginx as your webserver/proxy?

Comment: @cantuket i use apache

Comment: Sorry I can't be much help there

Comment: @cantuket for nginx please help me